# Retrieve field from session

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session-variables

I have a form where company can register, in this registration a user code is generated randomly... The CompCode is saved with all the other information in a database table as the primary key...

When a user is registered, they can log in... when they successfully log in, their compName is saved as a session variable

```
Session["CompName"] = TextBox1.Text;
```

Now once logged in, they have the opportunity to post a job, this job details is saved in another table called job... but in order for the job details to be related to the company i need the CompID

How do I retrieve the CompID using the session CompName

```
 protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string answer = "NO";
    string strcon = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\VC_temps.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Store-Jobs", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Job", TextBox1.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("JobType", DropDownList1.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("StartDate", Calendar1.SelectedDate);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Time", TextBox2.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("JobID", TextBox1.Text.Substring(3).ToUpper());
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("CompanyID", ?);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("PoistionFilled", answer);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Description", TextBox4.Text);

    con.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Labelinfo.Text = "Post successful.";
}
```

Comment: Do you want all your company info to be there in the session or just the CompCode...and then hit the db to get the rest of the associated info for the company ?

Comment: when the user successfully logs in, retrieve the associated compId

Comment: Have a look : [Read Values from Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Y0)

Answer (score 1):

if you mean by this that you wanna get the value from the session then this how you do it

```
  if(Compname == (string)Session["CompName"])
```

Comment: The `Session`-object can also be accessed with `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session`, but you'd only need that outside code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

Handle this in the stored procedure itself, pass the conmpany name stored in the session as described by @sleiman jneidi.

In the stored procedure, first retrieve all the compCode where compName = @compName, and then do rest of your thing.

Answer (score 0):

First I created a datasource like follow:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_CompID" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [CompanyID] FROM [Company] WHERE ([CompName] = @CompName)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:SessionParameter Name="CompName" SessionField="CompName" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I then added the following code in code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.getName();
    }
}
private void getName()
{
    DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource_CompID.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    DataRowView drv = dv[0];

    Session["CompID"] = drv["CompanyID"].ToString();
}
```

This works, it gives me what I was looking for, if there is a better why on doing it please feel free and comment